# How to convert and store configurable items in a multi-language web application?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, web-applications, multilingual

I have a **multi-language web application**.  I am converting all the controls i.e. labels, drop down, text, and messages *using resource file*.

**Problem:**

For example, registration page has drop down of Prefix- Mr, Mrs,Miss etc. This prefix data comes from a table and is configurable i.e We are having a configuration web page for the same.

There are many other configurable things and corresponding pages.

My question is how to convert this data into other language and how to save the same as it cannot be done with resource file.

Anyone having practical ideas can guide me.

Comment: Is This Mvc Application

Comment: This is a asp web application.

Comment: It partly depends on what languages you intend to create translations for. As soon as the language changes from LTR to RTF, a standard layout (for all languages) does not always make sense to the end user. Also some languages don't translate directly (or make sense).

Comment: Could you please provide table structure for prefix data, I have an approach and would like to use your structure to explain it how i use to do what you are asking. Thank you!

Comment: PrefixName, PrefixCode, ActivationState these are the three columns .PrefixName is the column to be displayed everywhere.

Comment: Hm why are you not storing the resource identifier as user data and then let the UI load the resources in the configured language? I do not understand why you want to save the localized string instead of the resource identifier.

Answer (score 2):

If it's user configurable, then it's not practical to use resource files, for users can configure whatever they need.

So, if I understood correctly, I think the only practical solution is having translations in a table for each value users enter.

Since users can enter values in any language it can get tricky.

I would choose a default required language, say english, so whenever users manage the values (Title or prefix in your sample), they have to manage them in pairs, i.e. their language and english.

So, if the locale is french, when they check the index of titles, they see two columns, one for french and one for english.

If it's the first time the french user enters the view, then there are no french values, so the user has to add the french translation for the english values al ready registered.

If the user adds a new [french] value, then she/he has to enter the english translation too.

It looks a litle cumbersome and may be not very practical, but it's an option!

Best,

PD: Hey, please share the solution when you get to it!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft .NET provides support for working with culture specific information using the CultureInfo class in the System.Globalization namespace.  Culture information can be set both at the page level as well as at the application level.

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Culture="fr-FR"%>
```

To set the Culture information at the application level, use the following in the Globalization section of the web.config file.

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <globalization
   culture="en-GB"
  />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

try this,

```
http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=957&pId=-1
```

Answer (score 2):

> For example, registration page has drop down of Prefix- Mr, Mrs,Miss
>   etc. This prefix data comes from a table and is configurable i.e We
>   are having a configuration web page for the same.

Since the values of the drop down are in the database, I think the translation should be in the database too.

The easy way is way is to have a field for each language in your `titles` table :

```
--------------------------
| Id | TitleEn | TitleFr |
--------------------------
|  1 |  Mr     | M       |
|  2 |  Mrs    | Mme     |
|  3 |  Miss   | Mlle    |
--------------------------
```

However this will not scale well if you have more language or if you want to add languages in the future.

The way I would do it would be to add a `localized_string` table like this :

```
--------------------------
| Id | Language | String |
--------------------------
|  7 |  FR      | M      |
|  8 |  FR      | Mme    |
|  9 |  FR      | Mlle   |
|  7 |  EN      | Mr     |
|  8 |  EN      | Mrs    |
|  9 |  EN      | Miss   |  
--------------------------
```

In your titles table and in any other tables where you need a localized_string you store the Id of the string :

```
----------------------------
| Id | localized_string_id |
----------------------------
|  1 |  7                  |
|  2 |  8                  |
|  3 |  9                  |
----------------------------
```

This way you can query the localized string in any language and you can add as many language as you want without modifying your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am currently implementing multi-language support in applications is through the following method.

- Create an abstract class called Language which all languages inherit from.
- Add abstract string property for each text string that needs translating.
- Each language that inherits from base Language class simply returns the localised version of the string.
- Create a global property to store the currently chosen language class.
- Get string values that need translating from global property rather than setting locally.

Although adding the translated strings is tedious, I find this method ensures all needed parts are translated while keeping the UI code as simple as possible.

The use of a base class also allows re-use of any methods or properties that can be used across all languages.

To try and give a basic outline the structure would go like this.

// Base Language Class

```
public abstract class Language
{
    // Field to identify the language by.
    public string Code {get; private set;}

    // Contructor that takes language code as parameter
    public Language(string code)
    {
        Code = code;
    }

    // Add the strings you want translating.
    // Making them abstract means classes that inherit from
    // this class must provide their own implementation of these strings.
    public abstract string Hello {get;}
    public abstract string Goodbye {get;}
}
```

// Example English language class

```
public class en_gb : Language
{
    // Constructor simply provides base class with the language code.
    public en_gb() : base ("en_gb"){}

    // By inheriting from Language these properties must be overridden.
    // Visual Studio will add these properties for you, so you simply need to add the return value.
    public override string Hello {get {return "Hello";} }
    public override string Goodbye {get {return "Goodbye";} }
}
```

// Example Spanish language class

```
public class es_sp : Language
{
    // Constructor simply provides base class with the language code.
    public es_sp() : base ("es_sp"){}

    // By inheriting from Language these properties must be overridden.
    // Visual Studio will add these properties for you, so you simply need to add the return value.
    public override string Hello {get {return "Hola";} }
    public override string Goodbye {get {return "Adiós";} }
}
```

You then simply have a global property somewhere.

```
public Language CurrrentLanguage {get; set;}
```

All elements that need to be translated can then reference the CurrrentLanguage property to return the desired string.

XAML Example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource GlobalValues}, Path=CurrrentLanguage.Hello}" />
```

Code Example:

```
Textbox1.Text = GlobalValues.CurrentLanguage.Hello;
```

Comment: where are you storing the translated strings?

Answer (score 0):

Extending the Resource Provider is likely the approach you'll want to take.

Review the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx (the context of this article is ASP.Net WebForms; take a look at the "Building a Database Resource Provider" section.)

http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/extending-resource-provider-for-soring-resources-in-the-database (this blog post actually applies what is covered in the above MSDN article, but to ASP.Net MVC instead of WebForms.)

I'm not sure what type of ASP.Net application you're building, so I thought it would be valuable to include references for both WebForms and MVC.

What is mentioned in these two references should give you a good basis on which to implement your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

To save configuration things which are entered dynamically by users in resources you can use [IResourceWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("Resource.resx");
// Adds resources to the resource writer.
writer.AddResource("String 1", "First String");
writer.AddResource("String 2", "Second String");
// Writes the resources to the file or stream, and closes it.
writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try XML format to Distinguish your lanuage

```
<Controls>
<Control>
<DropDown>
<English>Cities</English>
<Urdu>شھر</Urdu>
<Arabic>البد</Arabic>
</DropDown>
</Control>
</Controls>
```